# Shap: Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'sklearn.model_selection._search.GridSearchCV'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shap

Could someone please explain to me how to fix this code (a reproducible example):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold,KFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest 
#from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, recall_score, accuracy_score, precision_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer 
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,recall_score,f1_score,roc_auc_score 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from numpy import mean 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import std 
from sklearn.utils import shuffle 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pickle

import pandas as pd
import shap

X_train,y_train = make_classification(n_samples =1000,n_features = 20, random_state=1, n_informative=10,n_redundant=10)



def run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid={},output_plt_file = 'plt.png',model_name=RandomForestClassifier(),X_train=full_X_train,y_train=full_y_train,model_id='random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class', n_splits=5, output_file='random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class.txt'): 

      cv_outer = KFold(n_splits=3,shuffle=True,random_state=1)

      list_shap_values = list()
      list_test_sets = list()

      for train_ix,test_ix in cv_outer.split(X_train):
              split_x_train, split_x_test = X_train.iloc[train_ix,:],X_train.iloc[test_ix,:]               
              split_y_train, split_y_test = y_train.iloc[train_ix],y_train.iloc[test_ix]

              cv_inner = KFold(n_splits=3,shuffle=True,random_state=1)
              model = model_name
              rfecv = RFECV(estimator=model, scoring='accuracy',cv=cv_inner)
              pipeline = Pipeline([('feature_sele',rfecv),('clf_cv',model)])
              search = GridSearchCV(pipeline,param_grid=param_grid,scoring='accuracy',cv = cv_inner,refit=True)
              result = search.fit(split_x_train,split_y_train)
              best_model = result.best_estimator_
              yhat = best_model.predict(split_x_test)

              explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(result) #or when I change this to best_model, I get the same error
              shap_values = explainer.shap_values(split_x_test)
              list_shap_values.append(shap_values)
              list_test_sets.append(test_ix)

      test_set = list_test_sets[0]
      shap_values = np.array(list_shap_values[0])

      for i in range(1,len(list_test_sets)):
          test_set = np.concatenate((test_set,list_test_sets[i]),axis=0)
          shap_values = np.concatenate((shap_values,np.array(list_shap_values[i])),axis=1)

      X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(full_X_train[test_set],columns=columns)
      shap_sum = np.abs(shap_values[1,:,:]).mean(0)
      cols = X_test_df.columns

      importance_df = pd.DataFrame({
           'column_name':cols,
           'shap_values':sv
      }) 
           
      importance_df.sort_values('shap_values',ascending=False)
      print(importance_df)
      return


param_grid = [{
               'clf_cv__min_samples_leaf':[1,3,5],
              }]

run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid=param_grid)
```

From generating:

```
Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'sklearn.model_selection._search.GridSearchCV'
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Can you copy paste your own to a fresh notebook/ script, run, fix all the problems and update your question with corrected code ?

Comment: No problem, will do that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a `GridSearchCV` object to `shap.TreeExplainer`.

You can fix that that by passing the best fitted model of your gridsearch.

As follow:

```
cv = (
    GridSearchCV(
        model,
        param_grid=param_grid,
        scoring='accuracy',
        cv = cv_inner,
        refit=True)
    .fit(split_x_train,split_y_train)
)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(cv.best_estimator_)
```

Comment: In your code, `model`  is by default a `RandomForestClassifier` therefore i assumed that the best_estimator returned by `GridSearchCV` is accepted by `shap.TreeExplainer`.

Comment: I don't think it is accepted unfortunately, as I get the same error as described in the question (model type not yet supported) when I run this solution.

Comment: I think the answer may be to run search.best_estimator_['clf_cv'].fit(split_x_train,split_y_train)

Answer (score 0):

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(best_model[1])
```

is probably what you're looking for (best pipeline, stage 1).

Answer (score 0):

Your `result.best_estimator_` is such a complex pipeline that shap.TreeExplainer is not able to support

```
Pipeline(steps=[
    ('feature_sele', RFECV(cv=KFold(), estimator=RandomForestClassifier(), scoring='accuracy')),
    ('clf_cv', RandomForestClassifier())
])
```

To make it work, you have to "extract" the fitted model

```py
# Features effectively used in your best model
fitted_rfecv = result.best_estimator_[0]
selected_features = fitted_rfecv.support_
print(selected_features)  # [False False False  True ...]

# Test data with only selected_features
split_x_test_selected_features = split_x_test[:, selected_features]
print(split_x_test_selected_features.shape)

# Best model (fitted only selected features)
rf_model_fitted = result.best_estimator_[1]
print(rf_model_fitted)  # RandomForestClassifier()

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_model_fitted)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(split_x_test_selected_features)
```

Be careful with features' order in `split_x_test_selected_features`